# Extract angles from a lidar in turtlebot3

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A goal of mine is to detect an object from 1.0[m] to 1.5[m], using a lidar, and send angle information to another node.
I’m on elementary level of making a code. So, if you help me, It’s going to be really helpful. I want a code that can apply my project.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407308/extract-angles-from-a-lidar-in-turtlebot3/) by [kimsolphin](https://answers.ros.org/users/119773/kimsolphin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-10-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-04**:
You should subscribe to the lidar messages. Inside the callback, iterate over the message accordingly. Please read [Writing a Simple Subscriber (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29).

**Comment by [kimsolphin](https://answers.ros.org/users/119773/kimsolphin/) on 2022-10-06**:
Sir, I understand how to make nodes, but how can I access to lidar data? Could you explain me in detail?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I understand how to make nodes, but how can I access to lidar data ...

This sentence is confusing in a sense. Anyway, let's break your problem into pieces and solve them:

1. detect an object from 1.0[m] to 1.5[m], using a lidar

To do this task, we need to create a subscriber first, and then inside the callback, we can pick the angles based on our criteria. In this case, the criteria is the distance of the object.
2. send angle information to another node

To do this task, we need to create a publisher that can publish the angle data. Then, the published data can be acquired by other nodes easily.

Please see the complete code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
from std_msgs.msg import Float32MultiArray

pub = rospy.Publisher('/detected_object', Float32MultiArray, queue_size=1)


def callback(msg):
    # let's define a range
    distance_min = 1.0
    distance_max = 1.5

    result = Float32MultiArray()
    for i, r in enumerate(msg.ranges):
        # we need object in 1 to 1.5 m range
        if distance_min < r < distance_max:
            angle = msg.angle_min + i * msg.angle_increment
            result.data.append(angle)
    pub.publish(result)


def objectDetector():
    rospy.init_node('object_detector', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('/base_scan', LaserScan, callback)
    rospy.spin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    objectDetector()
```

I used [a recorded bag file](http://classes.engineering.wustl.edu/cse550/data/Mapping1.bag)  file mentioned in [this wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_pipeline/Tutorials/IntroductionToWorkingWithLaserScannerData) to run the above code. Please see below an example: Please see below a demonstration:

```
$ rosrun my_package object_detector.py 
$ rostopic echo /detected_object
layout: 
  dim: []
  data_offset: 0
data: [0.5559560656547546, 0.608904242515564]
---
layout: 
  dim: []
  data_offset: 0
data: [0.5559560656547546, 0.608904242515564]
---
layout: 
  dim: []
  data_offset: 0
data: [0.5030078887939453, 0.5559560656547546]
---
```

---

To understand the definition of [sensor_msgs/LaserScan](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) message, please see [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/198843/need-explanation-on-sensor_msgslaserscanmsg/?answer=198848#post-id-198848).

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kimsolphin](https://answers.ros.org/users/119773/kimsolphin/) on 2022-10-08**:
Sir, I really appriciate you, even if I'm in elementary level, I want to be like you in the future. ありがとうございます.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-08**:
Thanks for your kind words. Did the answer solve your problem? If yes, kindly upvote and click "mark this answer as correct" to tag this question as answered.

**Comment by [kimsolphin](https://answers.ros.org/users/119773/kimsolphin/) on 2022-10-31**:
I'm sorry that I saw your comment late , I just clicked upvote and 'mark this answer as correct'. Thanks,sir